# Why I'm obtaining a null list of elements with this regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I have a text with some POS-tags and some words. I created a regex to generate some bigrams that look like this: `[('word', 'POS-tag', 'word', 'POS-tag'), ('word', 'POS-tag', 'word', 'POS-tag')]`

This is what i all ready done:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --

import re

test_string= '''
Es ser VSIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
fácil fácil AQ0CS0 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
Por por SPS00 1
decir decir VMN0000 0.997512
algo algo PI0CS000 0.900246
malo malo AQ0MS0 0.657087
de de SPS00 0.999984
ella él PP3FS000 1
, , Fc 1
sería ser VSIC1S0 0.5
que que CS 0.437483
cuando cuando CS 0.985595
centrifuga centrifugar VMIP3S0 0.994859
, , Fc 1
algo algo PI0CS000 0.900246
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
hace hacer VMIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
bien bien RG 0.902728
sitio sitio NCMS000 0.980769
'''

regex = re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s\w+\s(RG)\s[0-9.]+\n^(\w+)\s\w+\s(AQ0CS0)', test_string, re.M)
print "\n This is a bigram:"
print regex
```

The problem is when i want to return all the words that have RG and AQ0CS0 that are consecutively, the final regex is empty. How can i solve this?. The output should look like this:

```
 This is a bigram:
[('muy', 'RG'),('fácil','AQ0CS0')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match unicode character, as you have in your example data, you need to set the unicode flag [re.U](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.U) or [re.UNICODE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.U)

```
>>> re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s\w+\s(RG)\s[0-9.]+\n^(\w+)\s\w+\s(AQ0CS0)', test_string, re.M|re.U)
[('muy', 'RG', 'f\xe1cil', 'AQ0CS0')]
```

Comment: Note that you might also need to make `test_string` a `u'''unicode string'''`.

Comment: Why?.. i thought i was only focusing in the POS-tag, by the way what other aproach could i use for only focusing in the POS-tags?

Comment: the ouput still null, what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the "á" character in fácil. It is not an ASCII alphabet, so \w cannot recognize it. You can use the below regex. It will solve your problem:

```
re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s.+\s(RG)\s[0-9.]+\n^(.+)\s.+\s(AQ0CS0)', test_string, re.M)
```